# How to override a function of mocked object?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, easymock

I got an object which needs to be mocked and override it's function. I need to use EasyMock as part our testing phase.

I looked over this example:
https://devlearnings.wordpress.com/2010/07/10/easymock-assert-arguments-of-method-call/

Seems like this example is too old and I can't find which implementation I need of `MethodCall` object.

Can someone please help me to override a function for mocked function ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation.
https://easymock.org/getting-started.html
https://easymock.org/user-guide.html